# javascript - Get position between two points by given length

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have two points which are `p1` and `p2`.

How can I get the position from `p1` to `p2` by a given length?

```
var p1 = {x: 100, y: 400};
var p2 = {x: 300, y: 500};
var len = 40;
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `p1.x + len` ?

Comment: If p1.y = p2.y, I think. @adeneo

Comment: Are you tried eval(p1.x + len) ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Your diagram isn't representing the data. You should be using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: You should probably have "tilted" the lines in the drawing a little, to make the point clearer.

Comment: Actually this is not a JavaScript but rather a mathematical problem ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between the two points using [Pythagoras's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
var xDist = p2.x - p1.x;
var yDist = p2.y - p1.y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist);
```

Then you calculate the fraction of the total distance covered by your length:

```
var fractionOfTotal = len / dist;
```

Finally you get the point you are looking for like this:

```
var p = {
   x: p1.x + xDist * fractionOfTotal,
   y: p1.y + yDist * fractionOfTotal
}
```

So let's say `len` covers 20 percent of the total distance. Then you add 20 percent of the x-distance to `p1.x` and 20 percent of the y-distance to `p1.y`.